# ¿Como realizar validaciones desde otro fichero utilizando express-validator?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estoy haciendo unas validaciones con `express-validator`, tengo la siguiente estructura de carpetas/ficheros:

**Fichero Server**

```
-api  
|-v1  
| |-projects  
|   |-routes.js  
-utils  
|-validations.js
```

El fichero `validations.js` contiene:

```
const { check, validationResults } = require('express-validator');

module.exports = {
  projectValidations: [
    check('title')
      .isEmpty({ ignore_whitespace: false })
      .withMessage(
        'El título del proyecto no debe estar vacío y debe ser diferente de espacios.'
      )
      .isAlphanumeric(['en-US', 'es-ES'])
      .withMessage('El título solo debe contener caracteres alfanuméricos')
  ]
};
```

Y el de `routes.js`:

```
const router = require('express').Router();

const controller = require('./controller');

const validations = require('../../../utils/validations');

/**
 * /api/projects/ POST Creación de proyecto nuevo
 * /api/projects/:projectId/tasks GET Consultar tareas del proyecto
 * /api/projects/:projectId/report GET Consultar/generar reporte del proyecto
 * /api/projects/:projectId/members GET Consultar miembros del proyecto
 */

router
  .route('/')
  .get(controller.all)
  .post(controller.create, validations.projectValidations);

module.exports = router;
```

Intento hacer pruebas del post que se ve anteriormente, coloco por ejemplo "title" con guiones `-` pero nunca me tira ningún tipo de error con los mensajes de los withMessage().

¿Podrían indicarme que estoy haciendo mal? O, ¿cómo hago este tipo de validación con las validaciones en otro fichero?

Answer (score 3):

Tienes mal el orden de los middlewares. El framework `express` los ejecuta en el mismo orden que los declaras por lo tanto en tu código

```
.post(controller.create, validations.projectValidations);
```

realmente lo que estás diciendo es:

1. Ejecuta la logica del negocio y mandale una respuesta al cliente (`controller.create`)
2. Verifica si el request es válido (`validations.projectValidations`)

Evidentemente esto está mal ya que se valida primero y luego se ejecuta la lógica del negocio.

La solución correcta sería:

```
.post(validations.projectValidations, controller.create);
```

También es importante entender que para pasar de un middleware a otro hay que llamar a la función `next` y es muy probable que en tu controller lo que ejecutes sea algun método del objeto res como `res.send()` por lo que el middleware de validación de todas maneras no se ejecutará.